# How to set login session in Joomla 3 as persistent cookie?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, session, cookies

I´m specifically looking for a way to make the login session persistent so that a user is kept logged in even after closing his/her browser.

Per default the login session is always terminated whenever a user closes his/her browser.

Does anyone know how to achieve this, is there a plugin for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In the Joomla backend go to:

**System** (top menu) >> **Global Configuration** >> **System**

and you will see an option called **Session Lifetime** which by default is set to *15*. This value defines the minutes. You can change it to whatever you wish.

Alternatively, you could use a plugin such as [Session Keeper](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/session-keeper) or [Forever Sessions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/forever-sessions)

Comment: Yes, I´m aware of the session lifetime settings in admin, but no matter how high you set the lifetime each time a user closes his browser the login session will terminate and the user will automatically be logged out. This is what I´m trying to avoid.

Comment: @GeniusDesign - Ensure the **Remember Me** plugin is enabled, then try using one of the 3rd party plugins I've included in my answer

Comment: "Ensure the Remember Me plugin is enabled"
I cannot find this plugin, is this a standard system plugin you are referring to?

Comment: yes, it a default system plugin

Comment: Yes indeed, I´m sorry I missed it because it is translated into my native language :)
It was already activated, though..

The problem is not with the session lifetime.
The problem is that Joomla uses a non-perstisten cookies.

Persistent cookies:
cookies are stored on your computer hard disk. They stay on your hard disk and can be accessed by web servers until they are deleted or have expired.

Non-persistent cookies:

cookies are saved only while your web browser is running. They can be used by a web server only until you close your browser. They are not saved on your disk.

Comment: As far as I know the non-persistant type of cookie that Joomla uses is technically called "Session cookie" and the type of cookie that I want to use is funny enough called "Persistent cookie"

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/760/whats-the-proper-way-of-setting-a-persistent-cookie-in-joomla-3-x